# How do you dynamically allocate a matrix in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm trying to build a matrix calculator using MASM and I'm having trouble trying to allocate the matrix dynamically.

For Example:

If a user inputs that the matrix is 3x3, I allocate in memory a space that holds a 3x3 matrix.

I was hoping someone could show me how.

Comment: Do you expect user to enter some crazy numbers, or you can get away with some hardcoded maximum, like 1000? Then just reserve 1million cells in `.bss` section, and use only part of that memory. If the cell is floating point `double` type = 8 bytes, that's only 8MiB of RAM wasted, not a problem with modern PC.

Comment: Do you really need *dynamic* allocation, or would a run-time variable amount of stack space work?  That's easier.

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to be able to create a multi-dimensional array with a capacity to fit the size of the matrix the user inputs when prompted on the terminal screen.

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim: Ok, then you can just use stack space to reserve `4 * n * n` bytes, instead of malloc/free or mmap/munmap (or I guess VirtualAlloc in Windows, since you're using MASM).

Answer (score 1):

> How do you dynamically allocate a matrix in MASM?

You don't dynamically allocate an array in assembler (because at that low level, *dynamic allocation* has no precise sense).

You could call, in assembler, some function doing dynamic allocation. For example, you could call `malloc` from some [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).

If you are coding some [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) application for some (known) operating system, you might consider doing some [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to change your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). On Linux, that might be (for example) [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

In both cases, you need to know and **follow the [*calling conventions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention)** used by the called function or system call. You probably need to read the [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) for your system. For Linux/x86-64, see [here](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)

The calling conventions are usually [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) specific and operating system specific. If you are using some stand-alone library or framework, that thing should also document its calling conventions.

See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/343797/40065).

You could also allocate on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (by changing the stack pointer appropriately).

Comment: But can I use a library such as Irvine32 to be able to dynamically allocate an array using "HeapAlloc"?

Comment: Certainly yes. Then you need to understand the calling conventions (relevant for that library and system)